# Spring boot with HQL gc overhead out of memory

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, heap-memory

So I am having a very strange problem, I have a spring boot application with custom HQL which fetches a projection of a table joined with another table and the projection is just 3 columns from those 2 tables, however once I do the find I get GC overhead limit exceed, even with 10gb of heap memory.
Problem is we are only getting 800 000 projections and in other places we have been getting more without any issues, however here we are getting an exception.
I've analyzed the error dump and I see that the projections are taking too much memory, but I can't realize why.
I've run out ideas so I am looking for some help if anyone has ideas what I can check next I would be grateful!

Comment: Have you tried profiling to check where the memory goes?

Comment: Yes, finally found out that the problem are the projections, when used as an interface they go through some converter and take a whole lot of memory, so once I changed them to POJOs there is no issues.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Data Projections that involve multiple tables might be backed by the entity object. In case that is the issue, I can recommend you take a look at [Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage) which you can imagine as Spring Data Projections on steroids. It will reduce the amount of data that is fetched and overall reduce memory consumption as well. Still, having 800 000 objects in the heap can still be problematic. When the out of memory error says that the GC limit is reached, it means that it can't reclaim memory fast enough. Maybe your heap is too big for the CPU or you simply do not have enough memory to hold that many objects.

Comment: Thanks will have a look, found that the problem are the  projections, when used as an interface they go through some converter and take a whole lot of memory, so once I changed them to POJOs there is no issue, however I will look at this to optimize further.